# How to assume lexicographical ordering

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, sorting

Suppose I have functions which depends on the symbols $c[I]$, where $I$ is some subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.
For example, $$f = c[1] + c[1,2,3] + c[1,2],$$ $$g = c[2] + c[2,1],$$

> Code:
>
> ```
> f = c[1] + c[1, 2] + c[1, 2, 3];
> g = c[2] + c[2, 1];
> ```

and I want to find the maximum between f and g, assuming that the c's are positive and moreover *monotonically decreasing with respect to the lexycographical order of their arguments*:

so for example $$c[1] > c[2] > \dots,$$ $$c[1,2] > c[2,1] > c[2,2] > \dots$$

so that $$f - g = (c[1]-c[2]) + (c[1,2]-c[2,1]) + c[1,2,3] > 0.$$

How can I define in a clever way this assumption so that `Max[{f, g}, assumption]` does the job for me?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code and examples as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
mymax[f_, g_] := With[{vars = Union@Cases[{f, g}, _c, Infinity]},
  PiecewiseExpand[Max[{f, g}], 
   And @@ (Greater @@ Append[#, 0] & /@ SplitBy[vars, Length])]
  ]

mymax[c[1] + c[1, 2] + c[1, 2, 3], c[2] + c[2, 1]]
(*  c[1] + c[1, 2] + c[1, 2, 3]  *)
```